# Pulling just one message at a time

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub

Im currently facing the problem that i want to realize a simple Master-Slave pattern, where the master initializes a job queue by publishing all jobs from the beginning to a topic. The slaves would pull those jobs everytime they have free working capabilities, pulling would be realized by pulling one job at a time. The code from the example code [on github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/v0.12.0/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/pubsub/PubSubExample.java) pulls multiple messages for a specific time

```
subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();
Thread.sleep(params.y());
```

I dont want that, i just want to pull one job message from the queue, let the slave do the work and after the work is done, call the pulling method to pull another job message, but just one at a time. Since I'm executing the jobs in an ExecutorService i want to ensure that i don't pull any messages, if my thread pool is filled. How would i realize pulling one message, fill that job into my ExecutorService and only pull the next job message, if there is a job finished, and a thread without work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulling a single message at a time would be considered an anti-pattern for Google Cloud Pub/Sub. You can control the number of messages delivered to your worker by specifying [FlowControlSettings](http://googleapis.github.io/gax-java/0.4.0/apidocs/com/google/api/gax/core/FlowControlSettings.html) via the [Subscriber Builder](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.12.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/spi/v1/Subscriber.Builder.html#setFlowControlSettings-com.google.api.gax.core.FlowControlSettings-). In particular, you could call [setMaxOutstandingElementCount](http://googleapis.github.io/gax-java/0.4.0/apidocs/com/google/api/gax/core/FlowControlSettings.Builder.html#setMaxOutstandingElementCount-java.lang.Integer-) on the FlowControlSettings Builder to limit the maximum number of messages that have been delivered to the MessageReceiver you provided. If each of your workers is individually a subscriber and wants to perform a single action at a time, you could even set this number to 1.

If you need more exact control over the pull semantics for your subscriber, then you can use the [gRPC library's pull method](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#google.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.Pull) directly. The [Serivce APIs Overview](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/service_apis_overview) has more information on this approach.